# Howto convert from Character to Date and merge Date and Time fields in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have imported a .csv file to a dataframe using the sqldf library, and the .csv starts with 2 seperate fields: "date" and time":

```
> head(df)
  Date     Time 
1 2021-11-21 10:05:17
2 2021-11-21 10:04:37
3 2021-11-21 10:04:37
4 2021-11-21 10:04:37
5 2021-11-21 09:52:25

> lapply(df,class)
$Date
[1] "character"

$Time
[1] "character"
```

How do i merge these 2 fields to a new "DateTime" field in the dataframe, so i can sort and filter by date?

What i want to achieve in the end is to be able to query for example like this:

```
select * where DateTime > '22-01-2022 18:00'
```

Comment: Base R: `as.POSIXct(paste(df$Date, df$Time))`.

Comment: `sqldf("select * from DF where Date || ' ' || Time > '22-01-2022 18:00:00'")` works as does this: `subset(DF, paste(Date, Time) > '22-01-2022 18:00:00' ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
as_datetime(paste(df$date, df$time, sep = " "))
```

so, adding `dplyr` library we can:

```
df |> mutate(newDate = as_datetime(paste(df$date[1], df$time[1], sep = " ")))
#
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  date       time     newDate           
  <chr>      <chr>    <dttm>             
1 2021-11-21 10:05:17 2021-11-21 10:05:17
2 2021-11-2  10:04:48 2021-11-21 10:05:17
```

and then you can `dplyr::filter(newDate >= as.datetime("2022-01-22 09:00:00))`

Grzegorz

Comment: Thank you so much @Grzegorz! I'm still learning R... :-)